# Fix crack in small blackboard

Tags: repair

I had a small slate blackboard in a wooden frame that had a 1/4-1/2 crack in it-enough to see through the crack on other side. Any recommendations on best way to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

The traditional way to join rock together is mortar.  But I assume you want to continue using this as a blackboard.  What I would try doing is removing the slate from the frame, and remove any kind of backing so that you just have the 2 pieces of slate that are each side of the crack.  Then run a bead of black epoxy on the crack and push them together.  You will have to probably make a fixture of some kind for clamping.  Use a slow hardening epoxy and clean it off the front of the slate.  I would also lay it face down on glass so that the pieces are flat while it's hardening.